# Cannot update to Ruby 2.3.1

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-2.3

I am trying to update to Ruby 2.3.1. I downloaded from [here](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2016/04/26/ruby-2-3-1-released/), and did:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Then I got:

```
/home/sawa/Downloads/ruby-2.3.1/lib/rubygems/installer.rb:227:in `check_executable_overwrite': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
```

How can I fix this and upgrade Ruby?

It turns out that Ruby is installed. But Ever since this happened, I have problem updating the gems. I get:

```
sudo gem update --system
Updating rubygems-update
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (TypeError)
no implicit conversion of nil into String
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Installed an hour ago via fresh rvm just fine. Are you using any ruby version manager? If not - this may be hard-to-reproduce involving existing installation

Comment: Just a shot in the dark - what is the output of `which gem`/`which ruby` and `gem env` ?

Comment: @Vasfed It is /usr/local/bin/ruby ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in bundled version of rubygems, as `existing` variable really can be `nil`, try patching that line like in newer rubygems:

```
question << (existing || 'an unknown executable')
```

Comment: That helped. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Locate the version of Rubygem that you want to remove in the gem directory in your system and delete it.

Then, Download the updated version rubygem file from 
[here](https://rubygems.org/rubygems/rubygems-2.6.6.zip)

Then, from your cmd, navigate to the download directory where **setup.rb** is located.

type the following command on cmd

> ruby setup.rb

That's all

Verify by checking the gem version with

```
gem -v
```